# Отсутствует libgmp-10.dll (Win 7)

Tags: windows-7, mingw

Решил настроить себе компиляцию из фара, настроил ассоциации файлов, но при запуске компилятора из фара возникает ошибка: на компьютере отсутствует libgmp-10.dll, которая на самом желе лежит в папке bin. Везде советуют добавить в Path (именно: не в PATH, у меня на вин7 даже такой переменной нет), я так и сделал, но эта ошибка по-прежнему возникает. Как исправить?
Самый популярный совет, которым якобы многим помог, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, правильный подход — скопировать dll в каталог к исполняемому файлу. Таким образом она будет «находиться».

Как именно скопировать файл — зависит от того, как вы компилируете. Если это makefile, просто сделайте отдельный таргет `deploy`, и собирайте все нужные исполняемые файлы и библиотеки в нём.

И кстати говоря, в Windows 7 существует `PATH` (Пуск → Панель управления → Система и безопасность → Система → Дополнительные параметры системы → Дополнительно → Переменные среды, перегрузиться после изменений). Но локальная копия всё равно более правильное решение.

Comment: Странным образом компиляция вдруг стала работать.

Comment: @typemoon: Хм. Вот и хорошо.